# Как сделать так, чтобы картинка отображалась и в Qt Designer, и в программе?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qrc, qmainwindow

Суть в том, что при выборе картинки из файла ресурсов, окно правильно отображается только в *Qt Designer*, а если через путь к самому файлу - только в программе.

Мне нужно, чтобы картинка отображалась и там, и там, 
причём без превращения **.ui** файла в **.py**.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

mainwindow = uic.loadUi("main.ui")

if mainwindow.property("fullscreen"):
    mainwindow.showFullScreen()
else:
    mainwindow.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

*Qt Designer* - отображает правильно:

[image: Qt Designer - отображает правильно]

---

На пуск не обращайте внимания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Qt Designer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Qt Designer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Найдите свой файл **pic.qrc** - посмотрите что в нем.
4. Мой **pic.qrc**:

---

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="pic">
    <file>world_map.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

---

5. Выполните **`pyrcc5 pic.qrc -o pic_qrc.py`**
6. Добавьте в свой main.py (у меня это **q1401451.py**) - `import pic_qrc`

**q1401451.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

import pic_qrc                                           # <----   !!! +++

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
mainwindow = uic.loadUi("q1401451.ui")                   # установить свой

if mainwindow.property("fullscreen"):
    mainwindow.showFullScreen()
else:
    mainwindow.show()
    
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

7. Запустите **`python q1401451.py`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]